# Django Rest Framework serializers.DictField constraint on possible keys

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a REST API output that looks like this:

```
{
  "something": "xyz"
  "something_dict" {
    "a": 10,
    "b": 20,
    "c": 30
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a serializer for that (mostly for automatic documentation generation purposes, but I believe that doesn't really matter), and for the `something_dict` field I thought it could be a good idea to use `serializers.DictField`.

The problem is, the keys that can show up in the dictionary are limited to a certain set (values of an enum type), but I can't seem to find a good way to define it.

Something like `serializers.DictField(key=serializers.ChoiceField(choices=[enum.value for enum in Enum]))` would be great but that's obviously not available.

The only reasonable way to specify this is to use a nested serializer:

```
class SomethingDict(serializers.Serializer):
   a = serializers.IntField(required=False)
   b = serializers.IntField(required=False)
   c = serializers.IntField(required=False)
```

But that's slightly inconvenient as the set of available keys is potentially dynamic (values of an enum, as mentioned previously).

**The question is then:**

Is it possible to specify possible values for `serializer.DictField` keys or is there any way around it to make it dynamic? (I'd like to avoid defining the class in dynamic way, if possible)

Answer (score 3):

Django Rest Framework provides a `DictField` serializer field that can be used to handle dictionaries in your API.

You can add a constraint on the possible keys of the dictionary by subclassing `DictField` and overriding the `to_internal_value()` method to perform the necessary validation.

Have a look at this example,

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ConstrainedDictField(serializers.DictField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # Perform validation on the keys of the dictionary here
        if set(data.keys()) != {"key1", "key2"}:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid keys for dictionary.")
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

You can then use the ConstrainedDictField in your serializer like this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_dict = ConstrainedDictField()
```

It will only accept dictionary with key `key1` and `key2`.

Comment: I'll give it an upvote because practically that will obviously work in practice, but this will not do what I want, i.e. generate a proper API documentation automatically. I'm generally asking about some kind of non-custom way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects

> The Serializer class is itself a type of Field, and can be used to
> represent relationships where one object type is nested inside
> another.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```